# show() checkbox with jqueryj

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

If a checkbox is hidden using jquery .hide how to show it again if we know the value in the following case

```
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="m_q"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="m_q"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="m_q"/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="m_q"/>
```

So the check box with value 1 is hidden how to use .show using jquery

Comment: you have two names in you code.

Comment: Your HTML is not right, you need `type="checkbox"` to make them checkboxes

Comment: Is that meant to be `<input type="checkbox"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input[value=1]").show();
```

Comment: Ah... the simplicity of jQuery :) +1 Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't show/hide the checkboxes the way you are doing, but of course I am just guessing as what you actually want. I would just use one checkbox and simply update the value:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="m_q" id="m_q" />
```

Now, instead of hiding `4` and showing `1` just do this:

```
$("#m_q").val(1);
```

Or if you can't add the `id`:

```
$("input[name=m_q]").val(1);
```

*Remember, "View Source" will not reveal the value change even if it is working.*